# Multisite WP-API json v2 : can i fetch all comments on all sites with a single query?

Tags: multisite, comments, api, rest-api

All is in the title, can i get all comments over the site network with a available endpoint ? Or do i need to fetch comments from all sites, one by one ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> do i need to fetch comments from all sites, one by one ?

Yes and you might try to do some json-merge in javascript for few sites, like with posts in [this article](https://torquemag.io/2016/07/combine-wordpress-sites-rest-api/) by Josh Pollock, but here are some alternative ideas:

For few sites you might try to create a custom endpoint where comments are fetched from each site via PHP and merge them for the REST response.

An alternative approach, for larger number of sites, I think you could use the same technique sometimes used to collect tags or posts from all sites:

Create a site that also collects sitewide comments through hooks like `wp_insert_comment`.

Then you could use the REST API to get all comments from that site.

The first plugin that I know of that used this technique was the plugin *WordPress MU Sitewide Tags* written by Donncha Ó Caoimh.

A quick search gave e.g. [WDS Multisite Aggregate](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/WDS-Multisite-Aggregate) that seems to be inspired by that plugin (I'm unrelated to it and haven't used it).

I also wonder if [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/) could help here, as it seems to be a possible [future](https://medium.com/chute-engineering/graphql-in-the-age-of-rest-apis-b10f2bf09bba#.6x5vkjy0b) replacement for the REST API?

Hope it helps.

Comment: for me, doing multiple gets in JS is a good way to overload the server. The only real option for front end side is to write your on end point

Comment: yes I think I would also consider a custom endpoint for few sites, but for only two sites I think the json-merge could be an option. What do you use to cache it in general? Transients, Memcached, some fancy Varnish caching or something else?

Comment: for this usage, probably transient